# Limit CSS Column Width to Length of Variable

Tags: html, css

I have a one-row table that is centered within a div. Two of the columns (i.e. cells) are filled with the name of a team and a round. I simply can't find a way to make the size of these columns correspond to the length of e.g. the team name.

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="greeting">    
 <table id="t03">
 <colgroup>
<col style="width: auto;">
<col style="width: auto;">
<col style="width: auto;">
<col style="width: auto;">

</colgroup>
<tr style= "height: 30px; width:auto;">
<td> Welcome, Team</td>
<td id="teamnamehere"></td>
<td> Please Make Your Decisions for Round</td>
<td id="roundnumberhere"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The corresponding CSS is:

```
#greeting {
    position: absolute;
    top: 385px;
    width: 980px;
    margin: auto; 
}

table#t03 {
width: 65%; 
margin: auto;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:18px;
font-color: #000000; 
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: From the HTML you provided, it looks like you're trying to make a form, in which case, you shouldn't be using a table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from trying to use a table for wrong purposes - they should only be used for data that genuinely needs a tabular layout to understand it. Use two divs instead, and make them inline-block in the CSS:-

```
div { display : inline-block}
```

and that will both show them side by side on one line and allow the divs to adjust their size to the length of text.

It has the additional advantage of being Responsive, so if you have an exceptionally long name or text too large to fit on a mobile phone screen, the second div will automatically drop to the line below!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `width: 65%;` from `table#t03`, it will have the width of its content.